# Slideshow on click image

Tags: javascript, image, click, slideshow

Right now I have a regular slideshow that goes to the next picture when you click on the > button.

I'm searching for a code that makes the image jump to the next image when you click on the image itself, so a slideshow without buttons.

Can someone help me with this? I can't seem to find a solid code for this.

```js
var slideIndex = [1,1,1];
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3"]
showDivs(1, 0);
showDivs(1, 1);
showDivs(1, 2);

function plusDivs(n, no) {
  showDivs(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showDivs(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="images01/designed1.jpg" style="width:50%">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="images01/designed2.jpg" style="width:50%">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="images01/designed3.jpg" style="width:50%">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="images01/designed4.jpg" style="width:50%">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="images01/designed5.jpg" style="width:50%">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="images01/designed6.jpg" style="width:50%">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="images01/designed7.jpg" style="width:50%">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="images01/designed8.jpg" style="width:50%">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="images01/designed9.jpg" style="width:50%">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="images01/designed10.jpg" style="width:50%">
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 0)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 0)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: your snippet is not working

Answer (score 0):

Either add the plusDivs(1, 0) function to the onclick on every div, or write custom code so on click of class 'mySlides1' it executes the plusDivs(1, 0) function. So basically clicking on a slide would execute the same thing as the 'next' button.